# Represent -1 as a true binary pattern

Tags: python-2.7

In contrast to python3,  the integers are limited in python2

```
In [1]: bin(-1)
Out[1]: '-0b1'
```

`-1' is represented as`-0b1',

How could encode '-1' as a true binary pattern like '11111111111111111......'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two's complement encoding to have any meaning, the integers need to be fixed-length. Python's integers are not, therefore such an encoding is not available for them.

Numpy does use such an encoding though. Thus,

```
import numpy as np
bin(np.uint8(-1))
# => '0b11111111'
bin(np.uint32(-1))
# => '0b11111111111111111111111111111111'
```

However, for Python's own integers, `0b11111111` is always `127`, not `-1`; `0b11111111111111111111111111111111` is always `4294967295`, not `-1`. Because Python integers are only limited by memory, any number of ones will only ever produce a positive integer.

Another way to force Python integers into C-like structures, this time without external libraries, is [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html). E.g.

```
bin(struct.unpack('I', struct.pack('i', -1))[0]) # 32-bit
bin(struct.unpack('B', struct.pack('b', -1))[0]) # 8-bit
```

You are correct that Python2 integers are limited, but they transparently expand into longs, which are not. Python3 doesn't have this division. However, I am not aware of a situation where it would change what I wrote above.